# Post order by custom fields

Tags: wp-query

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=16'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>     

                      <?php print_custom_field('time'); ?>
                       <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

this is my query I want the post is order by custom field 'time' in ASC

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like:

```
query_posts( array(
                  'cat' => '16',
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                  'meta_key' => 'time',
             ) );
```

See [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) documentation in Codex for more information.